Why does Task Manager report system idle process <5%, yet the Performance tab reports >20% CPU usage? (Windows 11)
I've never noticed a discrepancy between Performance and Details in Task Manager before, but for the past couple of months, they never match, with the Performance chart consistently showing higher CPU usage than the System Idle Process suggests there should be.
Just me?
Dell Latitude 5520, Windows 11 23H2, i7-1185G7 CPU, 64GB RAM.


